# Silverlight layout - unwanted spaces around the edge of the canvas

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I used the Silverlight Business template and started making some changes. For some reason now I have the browser coming up with both horizontal and vertical scroll bars. There seems to be a tiny white space around the edge of the silverlight canvas/object, but I can't figure out where it's coming from.

The object element is set to 100% for both height and width as in:

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
```

The body of the document has its padding and margin set to zero.

I've made sure that all the HTML elements have borders, padding and margin all set to zero.

Anybody got an idea where the extra spacing on the sides is coming from?

Regards,
Jacques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find 'a' solution. It seems that the iframe used for the history portion of the silverlight navigation technique was the cause of the problem. It has its visibility set to hidden, but when I added display = none, it removed the browser scrollbars and the small bits of white space around the edges of the sliverlight app.

This seems odd as Microsoft's Silverlight business application is virtually identical to mine and doesn't require this to be done.

Regards,
Jacques